# Jenkins + SonarQube 4.0 ClassNotFoundException occurs durng XHTML validation check using XML profile

Tags: xml, maven, xhtml, sonarqube

I am getting a **ClassNotFoundException** while attempting to run a SonarQube 4.0 analysis from Jenkins on a Maven project using Sonar's **XML language profile**. Within the SonarQube analysis, the exception is occurring while attempting to perform the *XML Schema Validation* check. What might be wrong?

This is the exception from the Jenkins build job:

```
0.0.0.0 ERROR - Could not analyze the file D:\Jenkins_home\.jenkins\jobs\XXX with Sonar Runner\workspace\XXX\WebContent\Login.xhtml
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.schemas.SchemaResolver.createLSInput(SchemaResolver.java:122) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.schemas.SchemaResolver.resolveResource(SchemaResolver.java:269) ~[na:na]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.DOMEntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(DOMEntityResolverWrapper.java:106) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:1671) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:909) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:569) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:519) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:485) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:211) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.createSchema(XmlSchemaCheck.java:147) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:234) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:227) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck.validate(XmlSchemaCheck.java:259) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.analyse(XmlSensor.java:69) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:72) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:114) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:150) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:190) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:185) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:178) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:58) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:155) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:143) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74) [sonar-batch-4.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45) [sonar-runner-batch1703873637256551857.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_24]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41) [sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_24]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance(DOMImplementationRegistry.java:146) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
at org.sonar.plugins.xml.schemas.SchemaResolver.createLSInput(SchemaResolver.java:115) ~[na:na]
... 52 common frames omitted
```

**Configuration**:

- Jenkins 1.509.2 job using Maven 2.2.1.
- Jenkins is running under Tomcat 7.0.11.
- Jenkins Sonar plugin version 2.1.
- Sonar XML plugin version 1.0.1.
- SonarQube 4.0 analysis using XML language profile.

I tried initiating the Sonar analysis from the Jenkins job using both a) SonarQube runner 2.3 via Maven post-build step; and b) directly using a Sonar post-build action. Both give the same result. Note that the SonarQube analysis still completes and I can see the results in SonarQube. I also tried running the job using Maven 3.0.3. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ticket created, indeed I've managed to reproduce this issue locally : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3356
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This appears to be JRE-related. The problem occurs when I use the Sun 1.6 JDK: java full version "1.6.0_24-b07".

Comment: When I configure the Jenkins job to use an IBM 1.6 JDK (java full version "JRE 1.6.0 IBM Windows 32 build pwi3260sr9fp1-20110329_01 (SR9 FP1)"), the problem does not occur.